# Sliding dataset using window VS Using strides in CNN

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

Reading a paper about [Conv-TasNet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.07454), model part,
I misunderstood about the configuration of the encoder model, which is a simple CNN, `tf.keras.layers.Conv1D()`.

For 8kHz 1-second segment, i.e., `(8000,)` data, 
It uses an encoder of 512 filters, length of 16, overlap size of 8. 
This can be easily implemented using `kernel_size=16, strides=8` as arguments of the above layer.

But I misunderstood by myself, making it as a point-wise convolution(which means `kernel_size=1`) and sliced each input into length of 16 and shifted by 8. (This required some works using `tf.data.Dataset` apis including `window(), flat_map(), zip()` and so on, but I could make the dataset into the form I wanted.)

So my question is, what is the difference between these two methods?

Both methods see the 16 lengths of the input, shift for 8 lengths. 
And both yields the same result. 
Let me give you an example to clarify.

Suppose we set `BATCH_SIZE=32`, and method 1 follows

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras

x = tf.reshape(tf.range(8000*32, dtype=tf.float32), shape=(32, 8000, 1))
original_encoder = keras.layers.Conv1D(512, kernel_size=16, strides=8, use_bias=False)
result1 = original_encoder(x)
result1.shape # (32, 999, 512)
```

And for method 2,

```
splited_x = np.array_split(x, 32)
splited_x = np.asarray(splited_x)
splited_x = np.squeeze(splited_x)
splited_x.shape

window_length = 16
shift_length = 8
datasets_x = []
for split in splited_x:
    ds_x = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(split)
    ds_x = ds_x.window(window_length, shift=shift_length, drop_remainder=True)
    ds_x = ds_x.flat_map(lambda window: window.batch(window_length))
    datasets_x.append(ds_x)
x_ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip(tuple(datasets_x)).map(lambda *windows: tf.stack(windows))

pointwise_conv = keras.layers.Conv1D(512, kernel_size=1, use_bias=False)

result2 = tf.zeros((32, 1, 512))
for i in x_ds:
    i = tf.expand_dims(i, 1)
    res = pointwise_conv(i)
    result2 = tf.concat([result2, res], axis=1)
result2 = result2[:, 1:, ] # discard the first zeros
result2.shape # (32, 999, 512)
```

I know this looks very ugly, but still both methods **watch** the same things, **yield** the same things.

Well, checking the `trainable_variables` of each layer, `original_encoder` layer has `(16, 1, 512)` variables and `pointwise_conv` has `(1, 16, 512)` variables.

Did I just do the same job?